# Handling image (bmp, png, jpg, etc) file merge conflicts in mercurial

Tags: image, mercurial, merge, bitmap

At a minimum, what I'd like is to have "hg merge" open up the conflicting versions in side by side instances of, say, MS Paint (ugh), so I can do the merging manually.  Bonus points for tool suggestions other than MS Paint.  At the moment I'm looking at [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the [merge tool configuration page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration) in the Mercurial wiki. You can make Mercurial launch a specific merge tool based on the file extension.

The Araxis tool look cool, but I have no experience with it (I use Linux). If that doesn't work for you, I would instead make a small script that will show all three images (the base version and the two conflicting versions) and let you choose the "winner".

Answer (score 0):

You could uuencode or base64-encode the images (you can set up hooks for automatic conversion), so that you don't have to deal with binary files when merging. However, merge usually works on lines and not characters and I don't how effective this is, since the enocding usually don't contain new lines.

Answer (score 0):

The [Araxis Merge website](http://www.araxis.com/merge/scm_integration.html) states that it will [integrate with Mercurial](http://www.araxis.com/merge/scm_integration.html#Mercurial). The product is commercial so if you have a license you might want to hit them up for information on using their product with Mercurial.

If you don't have a license and want to use their product, they'll probably help you get the demo working. Then you can mock the problem using fake repositories and test it all out...

If you are trying to stay way from Commercial, then manually configuration the merge tools on a per file basis is the only way to go. I don't know of any open source or free paint programs that would support merging.  As a sub for MS Paint, you could probably configure Paint.net to work with Mercurial (manually).

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a basic way to configure Mercurial to enable the merging of images using MS Paint.

First create a file `mspaintmergetool.cmd` somewhere on the Windows System PATH (so that Mercurial may find it), containing:

```
START %WINDIR%\system32\mspaint.exe %1
START %WINDIR%\system32\mspaint.exe %2
START %WINDIR%\system32\mspaint.exe %3
START /WAIT %WINDIR%\system32\mspaint.exe %4
```

Then configure Mercurial to merge images using this script by adding the following to your `.hgrc` or `mercurial.ini`:

```
[merge-tools]
mspaintmergetool.args = $base $local $other $output
mspaintmergetool.binary = True

[merge-patterns]
**.bmp = mspaintmergetool
**.png = mspaintmergetool
**.jpg = mspaintmergetool
```

If during a merge an image named `cat.png` conflicts, four MS Paint instances will open up:

1. `cat.png~base` - this is what the image looked like just before development split into the two streams you are now trying to merge back together
2. `cat.png~orig` - this is what the image looks like in the branch you are merging *into* (a.k.a. local); it is the image you started out with in your working directory before starting this merge
3. `cat.png~other` - this is what the image looks like in the branch you are merging *from* (a.k.a. remote)
4. `cat.png` - when this Paint instance opens, it initially contains the same image as `~orig`; your task is to edit the image in this instance into a combination of `~orig` and `~other`, save, and exit this Paint instance. Upon exit Mercurial will mark the conflict as resolved and resume with the merge. Note that the first three instances will not close automatically, so to avoid confusion with potential remaining conflicting images, you might want to close those Paint instances manually before closing this one.